# Access column from other child from same parent in Django template

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-templates

I have Stocks as a parent table, and Advice and Indexmapper as child tables. From my view, I am returning an Advice QuerySet, and in my template, I want to access Indexmapper.index_name from the Advice QuerySet.

model.py

```
class Stocks(models.Model):
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    sector = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    
    class Meta:
       db_table = 'stocks'

 
class Advice(models.Model):
    ticker = models.ForeignKey(Stocks, db_column='ticker', related_name='advices', 
                           on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    advice_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    high20 = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
  
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'advice'
        unique_together=(('ticker','advice_date'),)

class IndexMapper(models.Model):
     index_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
     ticker = models.ForeignKey(Stocks, db_column='ticker',on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                 related_name='indexmap', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'indexmapper'
        unique_together=(('index_name','ticker'),)
```

view.py

```
  ifund = IndexMapper.objects.filter(index_name='NIFTY 50')
  filter_stock = all_stocks_obj.filter(indexmap__in=ifund)
  result = Advice.objects.filter(ticker__in=filter_stock)

  return render(request, 'screeners.html',{'result':result})
```

In my template, I want to access IndexMapper.index_name. I tried this, but it's not working:

```
 {{result.ticker.indexmap.index_name}}
```

Comment: Note that a `Stock` object can be related to multiple `IndexMapper` objects. Which one do you want to show?

Comment: Hi Ene, I am printing every records
        {% for row in output %}
            {{result.ticker.indexmap.index_name}}
        {% endfor %}

Comment: any suggestion guys?